# Keyboard Shortcut To Add Trailing Comma? (Flutter & Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I would love to be able to use a keyboard shortcut to add a comma to the end of the existing line or the closing paren of the widget I'm currently editing, without manually moving my cursor around.

This would help with the code formatting a lot, so that I don't have to click or keyboard arrow my cursor to where I want to add the comma.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

I am using the `format code on save` option in **Android Studio** under **Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter -> Editor**

**More Information On Using Trailing Commas with Flutter**
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of <kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, which will add a comma at the end of the line you are currently editing.

If that is too cumbersome for you, you can also go to `Edit` `->` `Macros` `->` `Start Macro Recording`, then press the keys you want and then stop the recording in the bottom right corner.
Now, you also have the ability to go to `Settings` `->` `Keymap` `->` `Macros` and add `Add Keyboard Shortcut` to your macro.

Comment: Is there any reason, why this is not done by dartfm?

Comment: @Datasun `dart format` does not have an opinion on trailing commas. It will format differently based on whether you add it or not. Different people prepare omitting it or including it in different places.